# Load AppArmor profile inside Docker container

Tags: security, docker, r, apparmor

I would like to load another AppArmor profile inside a Docker container. The docker container itself uses the `docker-default` profile. The other profile is supposed to enforce the `docker-default` restrictions and more - largely restricting any file system access inside the container. As it is apparently not possible to change the profile inside the container, I post this question to inquire what other options there are.

1. One option that I am considering is to write a local profile that `docker-default` is permitted to transition to. Though, I suppose that this would have to be written into the `docker-default` AppArmor profile, which is not located in `/etc/apparmor.d`. The `docker-default` profile is apparently based on this [template](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/profiles/apparmor/template.go).

   How would I go about it? Do I just paste the local profile into the template, followed by executing `apparmor_parser -r -W template.go`? How do I overwrite `default-docker`? By naming `template.go` `docker-default.go`?

   I guess that overwriting `docker-default` is not the best option as those modifications might be overwritten when Docker is updated.
2. Another option appears to be running the container with `--privileged`. As that makes the container generally less secure, I would like to avoid this.

Some background on the setup I am working on: I am writing a number of [R shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/) apps which are deployed through [ShinyProxy](https://www.shinyproxy.io/) on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine. ShinyProxy spins up individual app sessions as separate Docker containers with the `docker-default` AppArmor profile. In some of the apps' functionalities, users enter R code through a [shinyAce](https://github.com/trestletech/shinyAce) console which is evaluated in the backend. Letting users execute code in the backend is usually not a good idea, but mandatory in this case. As I largely want to restrict the users' access to the file system and data stored inside and outside the Docker container, I intend to use the `RAppArmor` and `unix` packages. `unix::eval_safe` allows executing functions while enforcing one of the machine's AppArmor profiles. Because the `docker-default` profile is activated throughout the app session, `unix::eval_safe`, and internally `RAppArmor::aa_change_profile`, fail to load another profile.

What would be a secure and robust solution to this problem?